# Deploying Sinatra on Heroku

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra

im currently working on a Sinatra App and i was trying to deploy it in Heroku but im getting some problem.

Im following this steps on how to deploy in heroku : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-ruby#deploy-the-app

and i was stuck in "git push heroku master" i was getting this answer:

```
Failed to detect set buildpack https://codon-buildpacks.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/ruby.tgz
```

i was wondering on how to deploy my app on heroku. btw here is my code hierarchy.

[image]

i was running the heroku command in the Porfolio folder.

Portfolio
  -Portfolio-BE
  -Portfolio-FE

hope anyone can help me with my problem

Answer (score 0):

For sinatra and heroku you need to run the commands from the project root directory / wherever you have initialised git from.

It looks like the "Portfolio-BE" folder ..  head here ( check you can see the .git file by listing your directories from your terminal ), then do your git push etc.